# How to configure esbuild to use css-modules and sass/scss for when bundling?

Tags: css, sass, esbuild

### Background:

I am attempting to extend `esbuild`'s CSS support to include `CSS Modules` and `Sass/Scss`. I have therefore been making use of custom made plugins--utilising the esbuild plugin API. First, I tried:

- [`esbuild-sass-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-sass-plugin): As the name suggests, this plugin took care of `.scss` interpretation/transpilation. However, it failed to accommodate for `CSS Modules` (despite advertising its extensibility).

In accommodating for the missing support for `CSS Modules`, I added another `esbuild plugin`:

- [`esbuild-css-modules-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-css-modules-plugin): This plugin also failed to provide support for `CSS Modules`.

##### Relevant Technologies

- `Node`: 14.
- `esbuild`: ^0.11.11.
- `esbuild-css-modules-plugin`: ^2.3.2.
- `esbuild-sass-plugin`: ^2.2.6.
- `sass`: ^1.53.0.
- `typescript`: ^4.2.3.

### Advice/Help That I'd Consider GREAT:

- How would I best debug why these plugins are failing to properly provide `CSS Module` support?
- The culprit of what I am overlooking here and insights into what lack of understanding is causing this blindspot.

### Relevant Code Snippets:

**package.json - relevant build script**

```bash
"build:dev": "node build.js esbuild-browser:dev"
```

**build.js (entrypoint for esbuild)**

```js
const sassPlugin = require("esbuild-sass-plugin").default;
const cssModulesPlugin = require("esbuild-css-modules-plugin");

let options = {
  bundle: true,
  minify: true,
  minifyWhitespace: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  target: "es2018",
};

let builds = {
  "esbuild-browser": () => ({
    ...options,
    platform: "browser",
    format: "esm",
    sourcemap: "external",
    outfile: "build/esbuild/browser.js",
    entryPoints: ["src/browser.ts"],
    plugins: [sassPlugin()],
  }),
  "esbuild-browser:dev": () => ({
    ...options,
    watch: true,
    platform: "browser",
    format: "esm",
    outfile: "build/esbuild/browser.js",
    entryPoints: ["src/browser.ts"],
    plugins: [sassPlugin(), cssModulesPlugin()],
  }),
};

require("esbuild")
  .build(builds[process.argv[2]]())
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

**ScrawlComponent.tsx (note the `className` for `<span/>`)**

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles.scss";

type Props = {
  content: string;
};

const ScrawlComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const { content } = props;

  return (
    <span
      id="animation_link_target_text"
      className={styles.animation_link_target_text} 
    >
      {content}
    </span>
  );
};

export default ScrawlComponent;
```

**Output HTML (note ABSENT `className` for `<span/>`)**

```
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"><span id="animation_link_target_text"></span> </div>
    <script src="./esbuild/browser.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./esbuild/browser.css">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging esbuild path resolution with the [log level: debug/verbose](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#log-level)?

Answer (score 0):

CSS Modules support requires your css files to be named with the suffix ".module.css" or ".module.scss" in your case.

See esbuild docs for [CSS Modules](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#local-css)

To use CSS Modules with `.scss` support, you will need use [esbuild-scss-modules-plugin](https://github.com/ictrobot/esbuild-scss-modules-plugin#readme) instead of esbuild-css-modules-plugin.